# Application category for mailing passport to VFS for Canada TRV

Tags: visas, canada, vfs-global

I need to send my passport to LA VFS to get my temporary resident visa stamp for Canada. In the process of generating 2-way labels, it had asked for application category and instead of "original passport submission", I selected "temporary resident visa" option. I have already paid 75 dollars in this process and even though my receipt shows application category but labels do not have category. I wanted to know if I can still use my label or it needs to be corrected to "original passport submission" category.

Comment: How were you able to resolve this issue? Did you go ahead with the TRV category?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar inquiry and came across an answer that mentioned, `It can be either one.`
I attempted using both categories and found that each had the same amount of $77.**.

For those curious about the context, I'm going to use 'original passport submission' procedure, as explained in this link and the response gets from chat with VFS(In screenshot).

https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/timeline-trv-visitor-visa-from-usa.761873/

[image]

I'll provide an update once I get more information.

Or for anyone else still searching for answers on this topic, there are a few more discussions on the same subject which might shed some light:

- Using two-way courier service in USA for TRV stamping - https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/using-two-way-courier-service-in-usa-for-trv-stamping.763037/
- NYC VAC Passport submission & 2-way courier service - https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/nyc-vac-passport-submission-2-way-courier-service.757101/
- How to use two-way courier services in USA for TRV stamping - https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/how-to-use-two-way-courier-services-in-usa-for-trv-stamping.762979/

I hope these resources prove helpful to others with the same question. Let's stay updated and share findings!